# Send meeting schedule update via vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to replicate all my meetings in my OL calendar to Outlook.com.  When a new meeting is created, I replicated the meeting, delete all the recipients and an insert a new recipient with email address at Outlook.com and sent the new meeting.  I then delete this newly created meeting to keep my OL calendar clean.

All these work, except when there is a meeting re-schedule. My vba end up created a new meeting instead of changing the meeting at Outlook.com. I end up having two meetings at Outlook.com.  What can I do to create a meeting invite that is *not* a new meeting but to reschedule of an exiting meeting?

If I go directly to the point, under the AppointmentItem object, which property define if the meeting is

1. A new meeting
2. A reschedule of any existing meeting (and how does it tie to the original meeting)
3. A request to cancel the meeting

I did look at MeetingStatus but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

I need to change my design. I learnt that

1. Appointment.Copy not necessary create a identical duplicate.
2. By deleting the appointment, I lost all trail of the meeting and won't be able to change it.

Hence I redesign the flow such that a second calendar is created to keep the duplicated entries. I will keep the second calendar entries "sync" by using the ItemAdd and ItemChange event.  The entries in the second calendar will have all receipents removed except for a outlook.com account that I used to store the events.